# palindrome program (not working) i dont know why

Tags: c

I tried making a small program that would detect if you typed in a palindrome but for some reason, it just loops
ps I'm a beginner

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
char arr[100], arr1[100];
int i;

printf("type in a string\n\n");
gets(arr);

strrev(arr) == arr1;

for (i=0; arr==arr1; i++)
{
    printf("%c is a palindrome\n", arr);
}
for (i=0; arr!=arr1; i++)
{
    printf("%c is not a palindrome\n", arr);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strrev(arr) == arr1;` should be `strcpy(arr1, arr); strrev(arr1);` `arr==arr1` ==> `arr[i] == arr1[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` and `arr1` are **base address** of the two arrays respectively which would be different.One simple Code is here

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
char arr[100], arr1[100];
int i;

printf("type in a string\n\n");
gets(arr);
int len=strlen(arr);
strcpy(arr1,arr);
strrev(arr);
for(i=0;i<len;i++){
   if(arr1[i]!=arr[i]){
       printf("Not palindrome");
       return 1;
   }
}
printf("Palindrome");

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fgets instead of gets.
The first character could be compared to the last character. Then move the indexes toward the center for subsequent comparisons.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char arr[100] = "";
    int first = 0;
    int last = 0;

    printf ( "type in a string\n\n");
    if ( !fgets ( arr, sizeof arr, stdin)) {
        printf ( "fgets problem\n");
        return 0;
    }
    arr[strcspn ( arr, "\n")] = '\0';//remove newline

    for ( first = 0, last = strlen ( arr) - 1; first <= last; first++, last--) {
        if ( arr[first] != arr[last]) {
            printf("%s is not a palindrome\n", arr);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    printf ( "%s is a palindrome\n", arr);
    return 0;
}
```